# How do i handle JSON Data in Angular 2?

Tags: json, wordpress, http, service, angular

Hi I am new to Angular and I have been trying to learn Angular 2 so be gentle :).
I have been trying to use WordPress as my data API using WP API plugin. And have so far been able to get posts from WordPress. And below is my code for the data service.

```
import {Injectable} from "angular2/core";
import {Http, Response} from 'angular2/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
import {PostInterface} from './data.interface';
import {Headers} from "angular2/http";
import {RequestOptions} from "angular2/http";



@Injectable()
export class DataService{
    private _dataURL : string = 'http://localhost/wordpress/?rest_route=/wp/v2/posts';
    posts : PostInterface [];
    post : PostInterface;
    errorMessage : string;

    constructor(private http:Http){}

    getPosts():Observable<any[]>{
        //return this.http.get(this._dataURL).map((res:Response) => res.json());
        return this.http.get(this._dataURL)
            .map(res=>res.json())
            //.do(data => console.log(data)) // eyeball results in the console
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    //todo fix search

    getPost(filterid:number):Observable<any[]>{
         //filterid is the id of a specific post
        this._dataURL = this._dataURL + '/' + filterid;
        return this.http.get(this._dataURL)
            .map(res => res.json())
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }




    private handleError (error: Response) {

        console.error(error);
        return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error');
    }

}
```

In the code I get all the post data using the `getPosts()` method but I also have a `getPost()` method to fetch specific post. 
I was wondering if I could use the JSON data fetched by `getPosts()` and use it again in `getPost()` method. Currently what the `getPost()` does is call the `http.get` again I do not want to make `http.get` request again and again.

I want the `getPosts()` to make one request, fetch the data and store is somewhere so that other methods can use the data and do their specific manipulations.

Thanks

Comment: If you want to store the data somewhere, then just store it. Whats the problem in that. You can use a variable to save all the posts as array or map and then from there you can use it. Also you can use localstorage for caching the data so that you don't have to request it everytime you need data.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can firstly fetch your all data and save into one variable or another methods is where you subscribing your data perform `for loop` and match with your `filterId` where the process matches store that data into array and implement your manipulation according to need. here is example assuming your data is in array form..

```
import {Injectable} from "angular2/core";
import {Http, Response} from 'angular2/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
import {PostInterface} from './data.interface';
import {Headers} from "angular2/http";
import {RequestOptions} from "angular2/http";

@Injectable()
export class DataService{
    private _dataURL : string = 'http://localhost/wordpress/?rest_route=/wp/v2/posts';
    posts : PostInterface [];
    post : PostInterface;
    errorMessage : string;

    constructor(private http:Http){}

    getPosts():Observable<any[]>{
        //return this.http.get(this._dataURL).map((res:Response) => res.json());
        return this.http.get(this._dataURL)
            .map(res=>{
              if(res.json()){
                return res.json()
              }
            });
            //.do(data => console.log(data)) // eyeball results in the console
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }


    // Method in any file where you want to subscribe your data and wanna fetch specific post //

    singlePost: Array<any>= [];

    methodName(filterid:number){

        service.getPosts()
         .subscribe(res=>{
            console.log(res)   // Here you data whihc is coming from .map i.e getPosts methods using Http

            for(let i=0; i< res.length ; i++){       // I am asuming your data is in array from so performing length functionality
                if(filterid == res[i].filterid){
                    this.singlePost = res[i];
                    break;
                }
            }

            console.log(this.singlePost)        // This will return your single Specific POst without using `Http` again and again
         })
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Pardeep.. I'm new to this so bear with me. In my code the .getPosts() method fetches all the data on app start, my question is that can I use the data fetched by .getPosts() and use it in the getPost() method, so that i do not have to request data again and again instead use the data already fetched??

Comment: @abizit yeah sure in my answer `methodName` named method does the same for you. the data send from `.getPosts`  is subscribed in the method name `methodName` by doing so you don't need  to use `http` again and again.

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like that using the `do` operator to save the data into your service when the `getPosts` result is received:

```
@Injectable()
export class DataService{
  private _dataURL : string = 'http://localhost/wordpress/?rest_route=/wp/v2/posts';
  posts : PostInterface [];
  post : PostInterface;
  errorMessage : string;

  constructor(private http:Http){}

  getPosts():Observable<any[]>{
    //return this.http.get(this._dataURL).map((res:Response) => res.json());
    return this.http.get(this._dataURL)
        .map(res=>res.json())
        .do(data => this.posts = data) // <--------
        .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  findPostById(id) {
    if (this.posts != null) {
      return this.posts.find(((element, index, array) {
        return (element.id = id);
      });
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }

  getPost(filterid:number):Observable<any[]>{
    var post = findPostById(filterid);
    if (post != null) { // <--------
      return post;
    } else {
      this._dataURL = this._dataURL + '/' + filterid;
      return this.http.get(this._dataURL)
          .map(res => res.json())
          .catch(this.handleError);
    }
  }
```

Feel free to adapt this code to your needs.

Comment: Thanks Thierry, I was wondering how shud i approach if i want to load all the data on init and save it as a global thing so that I can use that data Itself to filter by id rather then making a different http.get request.. 
The way i'd like this to work is that i'll need to load the API JSON only once as it contains all the data I need.

Comment: You're welcome! You could move the content of the `getPosts` method into the constructor of your service and update this method to return `this.posts`. The constructor of the service is executed when the application has started if its provider is defined at the level of the `bootstrap` function

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.. so I shud be loading the DataService on the bootstrap itself as well right??

Comment: Yes, something like that `bootstap(AppComponent, [ DataService ]);`. Otherwise its instantiation will be linked to the component instantiation where you define it (`providers` attribute).